# Can we generalise the statement, "any well-defined function with domain the integers is continuous" beyond just the integers?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let us use the following definition for continuity:

For a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if $\forall_{\epsilon > 0} \exists_{\delta >0} \forall_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}}$,  $|x-y|< \delta \implies  |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

The statement holds for $\mathbb{Z}$, the proof goes as follows:

we consider the function $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$: given any $\epsilon$, we can just let $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$ (any value in $(0,1)$ works). Then $|x-y|< \frac{1}{2} \implies x = y \implies |g(x) - g(y)| = |g(x) - g(x)| = 0 < \epsilon$, as required.

It is easy to see that this argument holds for any codomain set $B$ such that $h: \mathbb{Z} \to B$ is well-defined, since $h(x) - h(x) = 0$ for all $h(x) \in B$.

Hence $h$ is continuous.

I believe a similar argument also works for, say, the set $C(a) = \{a^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ $\forall_{a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}$ (in this case, however, $\delta$ is not constant; it depends on $\epsilon$).

The common property of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $C(a)$ is that they are countable, so one may think that the argument holds for all countable sets, however this isn't the case. We cannot apply this argument to the rationals, $\mathbb{Q}$, since we cannot find a $\delta$ such that $|x-y|<\delta \implies x = y$ $\forall_{x,y \in \mathbb{Q}}$, as we could in the previous examples since given any $\delta$, there exists some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{10^n} < \delta$. Clearly, $\frac{1}{10^n} \in \mathbb{Q}$, so we can define $y = x + \frac{1}{10^n}$ and then $|x-y| = |x - (x + \frac{1}{10^n})| = \frac{1}{10^n} < \delta$ but $x \neq x + \frac{1}{10^n} = y$, at which points the previous argument falls apart.

So then what would be the generalisation of the statement? My intuition would be to think about functions containing only isolated points, but I am not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct generalization is to domains which are discrete, i.e. topological spaces $(X,T)$ with $T$ being the power set of $X$. This means they do indeed consist of isolated points.

Comment: Specifically, if $\mathcal{X}=(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then $\tau=\mathcal{P}(X)$ (= $\mathcal{X}$ consists entirely of isolated points) iff every function with domain $X$ is continuous. Indiscreteness (= no open sets other than $\emptyset$ and the whole space) satisfies the dual property: a topological space is indiscrete iff every map *into* the space is continuous.